# How to stop shift + mouseClick opening up a new window in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, d3.js

I using the Javascript library D3 and I have the ability to select multiple nodes by using `shift + left mouse click`. When I do this in Firefox (as my nodes have images appended) it opens the image in a new window/tab. I don't really want this happening.

How do I stop this event from firing ?

Answer (score 1):

with jquery:

```
jQuery(document).keydown(function(e){
  if(e.which === 16) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
});
```

update: 
How about instead of disabling shift, you try to disable the click. you might stop it if you attach a click event and use an event.preventDefault() on it

Comment: Ups, you're right, I was trying with a bad dummy code. Updated!

Comment: Can you provide some code? this could take forever if not

Comment: haha yeah sorry. Ill put together a JSFiddle. Can't use my original code because of a NDA wont be too long

Comment: it must be something to do with the D3 library I am using. When i put together a JSFiddle with just a simple html image tag it doesnt seem to open up in a new tab. But if i added an image through d3 it does open in a new tab. Ive looked at the BOM and in the d3 the image tags are like this <image><\image> whereas html image tags are like <img><\img>. Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rxzyLsbg/ the image on the left is simple html image tag, the one on the right is made via D3

Answer (score 1):

This is how in d3 you completely disable clicks

```
d3.select("#prevent_link").on("click", function() {
    var e = d3.event;
    if(e.shiftKey) {
        // CANCEL THE EVENT, WHICH WILL PREVENT ANY LINKING FROM OCCURING
        e.preventDefault()
    }
});
```

If you still want the link to work — but open in current window instead of new window — you can do this:

```
d3.select("#prevent_window").on("click", function() {
    var e = d3.event;
    if(e.shiftKey) {
        e.preventDefault()
        // Get the href of the <a> tag that was clicked 
        var href = d3.select(this).attr("href");

        window.location = href;
    }
});
```

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ff4ty93f/1/). The last example doesn't work because jsFiddle doesn't let you save scripts that contain `window.location`, so I didn't include the last line (`window.location = href;`) in the fiddle.

Comment: i wish to still be able to use shift + click to select my nodes. i just dont want any other window opening when i use it :/

Comment: So the 2nd code snippet will do what you're asking, no?

Comment: i see what you did, but that opens the image up in the same window. I dont want anything to happen other than selecting the node with shift + click (logic for this is basically just changing the nodes class). I dont want to open the image up. Ive asked another question here that may explain my problem better : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30325011/another-way-of-appending-images-in-javascripts-d3/30325269?noredirect=1#comment48745266_30325269 : thanks for the input btw :)