# Another way of appending images in Javascripts D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

Currently using this to append images :

```
nodes.append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "./randomFile/randomImage")
    .attr("x", -12)
    .attr("y", -12)
    .attr("width", 50)
    .attr("height", 50)
    ;
```

Notices its using "xlink:href". Now this works great except in Firefox.

I have the ability to select nodes by shift + click. Now in firefox when doing this, as it has a 'href' in the html tag, it opens up the image in a new window (like a link).

I have a fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/rxzyLsbg/

Which you notice the image on the left shift + clicking on that one doesn't open a new window as it has a 'src' not a 'href'.

How do i do this in D3 ?

I have tried changing this :

```
.attr("xlink:href", "./randomFile/randomImage")
```

to this :

```
.attr("src", "./randomFile/randomImage")
```

But doesnt work at all.

What I want is for the image not to be a link so it doesn't open a new window when shift + clicking on the image.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding the question, you could try to wrap it in an `a` tag and pass it the `target` attribute

```
nodes.append("image")
    .attr("href", "./randomFile/randomImage")
    .attr('target', '_blank')
    .attr("x", -12)
    .attr("y", -12)
    .attr("width", 50)
    .attr("height", 50)
```

That will open whatever `a` is clicked and will use the `href` as the content for the new tab

Comment: i dont want it to open anything. like in the fiddle i have linked to the image tag which has a 'src' and not a 'href' doesnt open up a new window when you press shift+click on the image ...

Comment: Ahh ok. I understand more what you're getting at now. The idea is to have the image *not* open when the user shift clicks, correct?